# Outsourcing your research to Kaggle for co-authorship or other non monetary options

Tags: publications, collaboration

Some parts of our research fall out of our expertise. We thought about creating a Kaggle challenge just for this part. But we lack fund resources for the reward, so we could not offer any money. We are thinking now about offering co-authorship in a paper, do you think this would work? Otherwise, which other things would you offer as reward in Kaggle apart from money?

Comment: Have you thought about asking questions on related stack exchange sites to see if anybody has any clue about that problem?

Comment: I will do that if in three days I do not get any answer here, but I had to start somewhere and I chose this nice place!

Comment: You may well be able to offer other incentives (which is why I'm not submitting this as an answer), but coauthorship is tricky, since it is highly constrained: everyone who makes an important intellectual contribution must be a coauthor, and nobody else can be.  For example, several other teams may submit ideas like the winner's (maybe with just a little less impressive write-ups or results); then they would all have to be offered coauthorship.  In the other direction, if nobody's results are useful, then nobody can become a coauthor, even if they put a lot of time and effort into the contest.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician I don't know how the authorship should work in this case but you are right that it's not something that can be simply traded. However, usually solutions very _and_ when writing a paper I don't need to put in co-authors all people with similar approach - I need to _acknowledge_ them, perhaps in form of citations. And IMHO it gives a natural framework when you choose your co-authors out of the solutions you want to use and only cite other solutions that make sense but you don't apply them directly.

Comment: I agree that if someone proposes a solution you don't use, then that doesn't necessarily require coauthorship, but the dividing line between use and non-use is tricky when the solutions are similar.  Basically, I'd separate coauthorship from winning the contest, and then invite as a coauthor whoever makes sense (probably the winner and possibly other contestants with the same critical idea).

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician AFAIK solutions on Kaggle are not mathematical proof-style. There is a lot of one's own idea, a lot of technical fine-tuning; not just 0-1 or a few main ideas for the proof. Moreover, before actually _asking_ participants, you see only a numerical result. So there is no risk of an unintentional plagiarism. And also one can set a threshold below which no authorship is proposed (personally I wouldn't promise any co-authorship but if the result accuracy is satisfying - asked the winner(s) for co-authorship).

Answer (score 6):

It's true that fitting the Kaggle competition framework is a bit of a constraint, but if you understand that framework and see how your problem fits into it, I'd suggest you e-mail quote@kaggle.com with a description of the data & problem (and ideally sample data), even if you don't have funding. We can see what comes of it!

(Disclaimer: I work for Kaggle.)

Answer (score 4):

This sounds to me like the textbook definition of a potential collaboration opportunity. I would speak with researchers in the computer science, machine learning, mathematics, and/or statistics departments and try to establish a long-term collaborative relationship. I would also speak with other faculty in your department to see how they handle this problem, which they likely have as well. It may be as simple as paying a grad or reasonably bright undergrad a few bucks an hour to crunch numbers. (Actually, you shouldn't take for granted that the grad student is reasonably bright... but I digress.)

This will be beneficial in both the short- and long-term, in a number of ways. In the short term, you'll hopefully get to analyze your data and generate a publication. In the long term, it's very likely that you'll need such expertise again, and you'll have the resources available for the analysis. Additionally, you'll find that having someone with analytics expertise on hand when *devising* whatever study you plan on doing can be immeasurably useful, as they will help you determine what measurements need to be taken and what data needs to be collected to ensure that you can get the most out of your dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Some competitions have "Kudos" (or "Jobs", or "Knowledge") as a prize, see [Kaggle competitions sorted from the smallest prizes](http://www.kaggle.com/competitions/search?RewardColumnSort=Ascending). I don't how it does work with proposing a competition (maybe it is not free).

I guess if the problem itself fits in the Kaggle framework (which is a pretty strong constraint), and you can try it for free (I don't know if it is the case), then why not. Especially as even two "Kudos" competitions attract 50 and 153 teams, respectively. Just it is on you to make it as attractive as possible.

Of course, intellectual contribution requires a co-authorship. But if I had the right expertise, I would run for it :).